# How to store the output of a recursive function in Python?

Tags: python, recursion, methods, return, recursive-datastructures

I have created a dictionary like so:

```
d = {1: {3: {}, 4: {6: {}}}, 5: {}}
```

Then I iterate through all the items and I can do it recursively:

```
def pretty(d, indent=0):
    for key, value in d.items():
        print('\t' * indent + str(key))

        if isinstance(value, dict):
            pretty(value, indent+1)
        else:
            print('\t' * (indent+1) + str(value))

pretty(d)
```

**My goal** is to store the output into a string variable in such a way that I can manipulate it. Therefore the result should be something like this:

```
msg ="""
1
        3
        4
                6
5
"""
```

**I tried** to reach my goal with the following implementation:

```
def pretty(d, indent=0, indent_before=0, msg_old=""):
    for key, value in d.items():
        #print('\t' * indent + str(key) + '({})({})'.format(indent,indent_before))
        msg = msg_old+'\t' * indent + str(key) + '({})({})\n'.format(indent,indent_before)
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            pretty(value, indent+1, indent, msg)
        else:
            print('\t' * (indent+1) + str(value))
    return msg
    
msg = pretty(result)
print(msg)
```

But the output of my attempt is: `None`

Would you be able to suggest a smart and elegant way to achieve the desired result?

Comment: Please explain in detail what "without success" means, how your function was *supposed* to work, and at what point it first went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that in your recursive call you are discarding the return value (i.e. calling `pretty` but not appending the return value to the existing message).

Here is a solution based closely on your original code.

```
d = {1: {3: {}, 4: {6: {}}}, 5: {}}

def pretty(d, indent=0):
    msg = ''
    for key, value in d.items():
        msg += '\t' * indent + str(key) + '\n'
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            msg += pretty(value, indent+1)  # <=== see how return value is used
        else:
            msg += '\t' * (indent+1) + str(value) + '\n'
    return msg

print(pretty(d))
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you are trying to implement your own solution but you never mentioned the builtin [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html#pprint.pformat) library/function that does this all for you:

```
from pprint import pformat
d = {1: {3: {}, 4: {6: {}}}, 5: {}}
print(pformat(d, indent=0))
```

---

```
{1: {3: {}, 4: {6: {}}}, 5: {}}
```

Comment: OP wants a string returned, so you probably want `pprint.pformat` rather than `pprint.pprint`.

Answer (score 0):

If your dict is well-formed, then you can use:

```
>>> def pretty(d, indent=0):
...     return "".join(["\n" + "\t" * indent + str(k) +
...                     pretty(v, indent + 1) for k, v in d.items()])
...
>>> d = {1: {3: {}, 4: {6: {}}}, 5: {}}
>>> pretty(d)
'\n1\n\t3\n\t4\n\t\t6\n5'
>>> print(pretty(d))

1
        3
        4
                6
5
```